# How to test observable in angular 2

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, rxjs, angular2-observables

Have my test suite setup, but can't figure out how to test an observable that relies on a 3rd party module to get filenames off a server.

**How do I mock an observable so that I can test my `openConnection()` method?**  I don't want to outright replace it with a spy, just mock an observable.

> ssh.service.ts

```
openConnection(): Observable<any> {
            this.Client = this.ssh.getClient();

            return Observable.create((obs: Observer<string>) => {
                let remotePathToList = '/home';
                var conn = this.Client;
                this.Client.on('ready', ()=>{
                    conn.sftp((err:any, sftp:any)=>{
                        if (err) throw err;
                        sftp.readdir(remotePathToList, (err:any, list:any)=>{
                            conn.end();
                            obs.next(list);
                            //obs.complete(); // required, otherwise your subscription would never close
                        })
                    })
                }).connect(this.connSettings);
            });
        }
```

> ssh.spec.ts

```
    describe('SSH service', () => {
    let subject: SshService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [
                SshService
            ]
        });
    });

    beforeEach(inject([SshService], (sshService: SshService) => {
        subject = sshService;
    }));

    it('should mock an observable', () => {

        var res =   Observable.create((obs: Observer<string>) => {
            obs.next('hello');
        });
        expect(subject.openConnection()).toEqual(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you want to mock an observable, or test it?  It's not very unit-testy to have it open the connection like that.

Comment: are you saying you want the returned observable to equal `res`, and you're trying to create a `res` that matches what you expect?

Comment: I know it's not very unit-testy to have it open a connection too, I"m just trying to get all the components to work & then I can go back and create a getData() method that the observable calls.

Basically I'm just trying to figure out how to resolve my openConnection() observable in the test with some dummy data and test that openConnection() returns that dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should "fake" a resolved observable for you from the SSH Service.

```
describe('SSH service', () => {
let fakeData = "Fake Data I want to return"

let fakeSSHService = {
    openConnection: () => Observable.of(fakeData)
}

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            { provide: SshService, useValue: fakeSSHService }
        ]
    });
});
```